# Replicating imp.load_dynamic with importlib (or something else) in >Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, dllimport

The video editing software DaVinci Resolve has a python api to control the software remotely. Connecting to it is fairly easy. Blackmagic gives us this code to connect:

```
import imp
lib = "C:\\Program Files\\Blackmagic Design\\Davinci Resolve\\fusionscript.dll"
dvr_script = imp.load_dynamic("fusionscript", lib)
resolve = dvr_script.scriptapp("Resolve")
```

In python 3.6 and earlier, this worked - but imp is deprecated and removed completely as of python 3.7, and replaced with importlib.

I'm currently stuck in python 3.7 in my work environment, so I need to figure out an alternative. importlib doesn't appear to have any matching functions, and the other solutions I've seen online (like manually recreating the missing load_dynamic function) seem to crash python.

This is the code to manually recreate it, that just closes python immediately. No errors, just a hard crash:

```
from importlib._bootstrap import _ERR_MSG, _exec, _load, _builtin_from_name

def load_dynamic(name, path, file=None):
        """**DEPRECATED**

        Load an extension module.
        """
        import importlib.machinery
        loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(name, path)

        # Issue #24748: Skip the sys.modules check in _load_module_shim;
        # always load new extension
        spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
            name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
        return _load(spec)

        
lib = "C:\\Program Files\\Blackmagic Design\\Davinci Resolve\\fusionscript.dll"
dvr_script = load_dynamic("fusionscript", lib)
resolve = dvr_script.scriptapp("Resolve")
print(resolve)
```

Is it possible to import this .dll in python 3.7, or has something internally in python changed that has broken this functionality?

Comment: Which line crashes? Also what's the exit code? Although deprecated, *imp*  exists in *Python 3.9*.

Comment: Not sure how to find the exit code, it just ends. Seems to shut down on _load(spec)

Comment: To recap: does it work in newer *Python* versions (even if *imp* is deprecated)?  Does this behavior occur when loading other (*.dll*) modules?

Comment: Same result in 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. I don't have any other DLLs to test in a similar fashion unfortunately.

Comment: *ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit\_dll)* with *DaVinci 17.1.1.9* and all *Python* versions that you mentioned. Do you have some official doc stating to do things like this?